# Colour scheme for the Raspberry Pi meta site

Tags: feature-request

I know colour is personal taste, but here me out here. I find the main Raspberry Pi site to be colourful, inviting and representative of the colours I associate with the Pi.

Then there is the Raspberry Pi meta site, who's colour scheme is very dark, black/grey. I personally find this uninviting and other people may find this as well. Which is a shame because this is the site where we can make changes to improve the main site.

So perhaps a colour change, or more information on the main site would encourage people to use the meta site more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The greyscale colour scheme for meta is standard across all Stack Exchange sites. The main sites are always in colour, meta sites are always greyscale. Take a look:

Stack Overflow Meta
[image: SO meta]

Super User Meta
[image: SU meta]

Random Beta Site (3D printing Meta)
[image: 3D meta]

<sup>(Note that meta.stackexchange is special in that it's 'main site' *is* a meta site, but it still gets colours like other main sites.)</sup>

Even if our community agrees with you and thinks that the colour scheme should be changed, it would be highly unlikely that it would:

- Changes to site design after graduation (apart from bugfixes etc) are extremely rare, since they require lots of extra work by the designers (which are currently under short supply, due to changes in the way sites graduate, which brought a large backlog of sites requiring a design)
- If they broke the standard on RPi.SE, they would probably need to redesign every single SE meta site. This would require a network-wide proposal to gain lots of support before SE even *thinks* about changing it.